# How to apply search also in child node

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## demo.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,StringProperty

Window.size = (700, 530)


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


tree = []

tree = [{'node_id': 'Capital Account',
         'children': [{'node_id': 'Reserves & Surplus',
                       'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1',
                                     'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1.1',
                                                   'children': []}]},
                                    {'node_id': '1.1.2',
                                     'children': []},
                                    {'node_id': '1.1.3',
                                     'children': []}]},
                       {'node_id': '1.2',
                        'children': []}]},
        {'node_id': 'Current Assests',
         'children': []}]


class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass

class TestViewLabel():
    pass


class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    ti = ObjectProperty()
    abc = StringProperty('c')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                       hide_root=False,
                       indent_level=4)
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.treeview.children]:
            self.treeview.remove_widget(child)

    def filter(self, f):
        self.treeview.clear_widgets()
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)
        new_tree = []
        for n in tree:
            if f.lower() in n['node_id'].lower():
                new_tree.append(n)
        for branch in new_tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)

        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)



class CityScreen(Screen):
    groupName = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)
    statecode = StringProperty('')

    def display_states(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeviewGroup()
            self.popup.filter(instance.text)
            self.popup.open()

    def select_node(self, node):
        '''Select a node in the tree.
            '''

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TreeViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.stateName.text = self.text
        app.root.select_node(self)
        app.root.popup.dismiss()

<TestViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.stateName.text = self.text
        app.root.select_node(self)
        app.root.popup.dismiss()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    id: treeview
    treeview: treeview
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: ti
            size_hint_y: .1
            text: root.abc
            on_text: root.filter(self.text)
        BoxLayout:
            id: treeview
            #on_press: root.select_node(self.text)
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Close"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

CityScreen:
    stateName: stateName

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Text'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: stateName
            on_text: root.display_states(self)

        #Spinner:
            #text: "State Code"
            #values: ["111", "112", "113", "114"]
            #values: app.r
            #background_color: color_button if self.state == 'normal' else color_button_pressed
            #background_down: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/spinner'
            #color: color_font
            #option_cls: Factory.get("MySpinnerOption")
            #size_hint: None, None

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'
            on_press: root.insert_data(stateName.text)


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()

        Label:

        Label:
```

1. When i type something in text TextBox then a pop up will be show.Then how to pass value from text TextBox to searchbox in pop up.
2. SearchBox working perfect for parent node.It's not working for child node.How will this work?

Comment: have you tried binding the values together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. When i type something in text TextBox then a pop up will be show.Then how to pass value from text TextBox to searchbox in pop up like attached image.

Since you have the text input property in your popup when you open it you can pass the text:

```
...
<TreeviewGroup>:
    id: treeview
    treeview: treeview
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False
    ti: ti
    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: ti
            size_hint_y: .1
            on_text: root.filter(self.text)
```

then in the .py:

```
...

class CityScreen(Screen):
    groupName = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)
    statecode = StringProperty('')

    def display_states(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeviewGroup()
            self.popup.ti.text = instance.text
            self.popup.filter(instance.text)
            self.popup.open()
...
```

> 2 SearchBox working perfect for parent node.It's not working for child node.How will this work?

That was not very easy to do, that question deserved a bounty

To make a filter when the treeView has children that are also parents I do many recursion

first, add those functions to your .py

```
...
def get_children(n):
    '''get all the children in the node whithout her children'''
    if len(n['children']) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        children = [e['node_id'] for e in n['children']]
        for child in n['children']:
            children.extend([c for c in get_children(child)])
        return children


def get_children2(n, t):
    '''get the node with n as id'''
    if t is []:
        return False
    else:
        for child in t:
            if child['node_id'] == n:
                return child
            else:
                r = get_children2(n, child['children'])
                if r:
                    return r

def roots(n):
    '''return the roots (if a node have child it is a root)'''
    if len(n['children']) == 0:
        return [None]
    else:
        l = [n['node_id']]
        for c in n['children']:
            l.extend(roots(c))
        return l


def get_roots(t):
    '''this one is just to remove the None from the result of the first one'''
    fl = []
    for n in t:
        l = roots(n)
        li = []
        for e in l:
            if e is not None:
                li.append(e)
        fl.extend(li)
        if len(n['children']) == 0:
            fl.append(n['node_id'])
    return fl

...
```

Now you can change the filter method of the TreeView:

```
...
class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    ti = ObjectProperty()

    ...

    def filter(self, f):
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)
        l = []
        l_roots = get_roots(tree)
        dict_roots = []
        for node in self.tv.iterate_all_nodes():
            l.append(node)
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if l[i].text in l_roots:
                dict_roots.append({'ind': i, 'id': l[i].text})
        roots_childs = {}
        for e in l:
            try:
                nod = get_children2(e.text, tree)
                roots_childs[e.text] = get_children(nod)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        to_remove = []            
        for e in roots_childs:
            for child in roots_childs[e]:
                if child not in l_roots:
                    if f.lower() not in child.lower():
                        if child not in to_remove:
                            to_remove.append(child)
            n = 0
            for child in roots_childs[e]:
                if child in to_remove:
                    n += 1
            if n == len(roots_childs[e]):
                if f.lower() not in e.lower():
                    to_remove.append(e)
        for n in l:
            if n.text in to_remove:
                self.tv.remove_node(n)
```

## Update I have forgotten to add ti in the TreeViewGroop in the kv it's fixed now

Comment: You are such a genius.Again you saved me.Thanks from bottom of my hearts.